# How to Convert python time.time() to Java

Tags: java, python, datetime

How do I convert the following python code to Java?

```
import time
 str(int(time.time() * 1e6))
```

I have tried the following snippet in my Java project.

```
private static String runPython(String script) throws  Exception{
         File file = new File("test.py");
         if(file.exists()) {
             file.delete();
         }
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.py"));
         out.write(script);
         out.close();
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py ");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String ret = in.readLine();
         return  ret+"";

}
private static String getFromPython() {
    try {
         String prg = "import time\nprint str(int(time.time() * 1e6))\n";

         return  runPython(prg)+"";
     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return null;

}


public static String getFromJava() {
    String result = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) * 1e6)+"";
    return result;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Python Version: "+getFromPython());
    System.out.println("Java Version: "+getFromJava());
}
```

This are the different results am getting

```
run:
Python Version: 1417515400105953
Java Version: 1.4175154E15
```

Any one with a better approach? How is the time.time() in python different from System.currentTimeInMillies() in Java?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "different results"? Please give examples. Also note that your current Java code wouldn't compile... it's always worth giving valid code, unless you're trying to ask about a compile-time failure.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have corrected and improved question, if it makes you any happier. But the first answer provided worked for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't actually *explain* the difference though. I'll add an extra answer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints - just because you got an answer you like without asking a decent question doesn't mean it's a good idea to keep doing so. In general, the better the question is, the better the answers will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That was really informative. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. Helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values you're getting are very similar - it's just that the representations are different. That's primarily because in the Java version you're multiplying by `1e6` which is a floating-point literal, so the result is a `double`, which is being represented in scientific notation due to its size. Python is a bit freer with its numeric types, and is choosing to display the result without using scientific notation.

If instead you multiply by the integer literal 1000000 you'd get something like `"1417515400000000"` - which looks closer to the Python version, but is truncated to the second.

If instead of dividing by 1,000 and then multiplying by 1,000,000 you *just* multiplied by 1,000, you'd get something more like `"1417515400105000"`. That's still truncated to the millisecond, but I suspect that your clock isn't likely to be more accurate than that anyway.

As an aside, I'd recommend using `String.valueOf(x)` to convert non-string types to strings rather than using `x + ""` - it better describes what you're trying to do, as you're really not trying to perform a concatenation at all. So I'd suggest that your `getValueFromJava` method should be:

```
public static String getFromJava() {
    return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);
}
```

(It's unclear why you *need* this as a string in the first place, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `time.time()` is `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0`.

The equivalent of

```
str(int(time.time() * 1e6))
```

is therefore

```
String.valueOf((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0) * 1e6)
```

which can be simplified as

```
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's almost the same except that in python you are getting 16 digits (10 digits before decimal by time.time() + 6 post decimal) while in java you get 13 digits. Your equivalent code would be

```
String result = (System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000) + "";
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Also, thanks for being smart enough to know what I was looking for without bothering with the correctness of my question.